# Nested loops to determine students in two classes (both)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to use nested loops for this exercise.

I have two class lists and need to determine which students are in both classes. I have written the code and it works but now my for loop is iterating over all the students again and prints the results the same as the iteration instead of just the actual students (in both classes). It does work if I put the for students in cs_students in line with the for students in maths_students but then it's not nested.

My code is as follows:

```
math_students = ["Audrey", "Ben", "Julia", "Paul", "Gerry", "Sue",
             "Helena", "Harry", "Marco", "Rachel", "Tina", "Mark", "Jackson"]
cs_students = ["William", "Aroha", "Melissa", "Sue", "Ben", "Audrey", "Susan", "Mark", "Hemi", "Brendan", "Paul", "Barry", "Julia"]


for student in math_students:
    count = 0
    for student in cs_students:
        if student in math_students:
        count +=1
        print("Student:", student, "is enrolled in both classes")
print(count, "Students are enrolled in Computer Science and Maths")
```

My output is:

```
Student: Sue is enrolled in both classes
Student: Ben is enrolled in both classes
Student: Audrey is enrolled in both classes
Student: Mark is enrolled in both classes
Student: Paul is enrolled in both classes
Student: Julia is enrolled in both classes
Student: Sue is enrolled in both classes
Student: Ben is enrolled in both classes
Student: Audrey is enrolled in both classes
Student: Mark is enrolled in both classes
Student: Paul is enrolled in both classes
Student: Julia is enrolled in both classes and so on.......
6 Students are enrolled in Computer Science and Maths
```

Comment: thanks for the edit zero323.  I didn't realise that could be done!

Comment: Note: another way to do this without loops is to use sets. you can do something like `math_set = set(math_students)` and `cs_set = set(cs_students)` and then find the intersection of both using `in_both_classes = math_set.intersection(cs_set)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the same variable, `student`, in both for-loops. Doing that prevents you from comparing the list values with each other.

That, and simple if-statement would do the trick :

```
math_students = ["Audrey", "Ben", "Julia", "Paul", "Gerry", "Sue",
             "Helena", "Harry", "Marco", "Rachel", "Tina", "Mark", "Jackson"]
cs_students = ["William", "Aroha", "Melissa", "Sue", "Ben",
             "Audrey","Susan", "Mark", "Hemi", "Brendan", "Paul", "Barry", "Julia"]

count = 0
for student1 in math_students:     #change this to student1
    for student2 in cs_students:   #change this to student2
        if student1 ==student2:    #check if student1 is equal to student 2
            count +=1
            print("Student:", student2, "is enrolled in both classes") #print student2
print(count, "Students are enrolled in Computer Science and Maths")
```

Now this would output:

```
>>>
('Student:', 'Audrey', 'is enrolled in both classes')
('Student:', 'Ben', 'is enrolled in both classes')
('Student:', 'Julia', 'is enrolled in both classes')
('Student:', 'Paul', 'is enrolled in both classes')
('Student:', 'Sue', 'is enrolled in both classes')
('Student:', 'Mark', 'is enrolled in both classes')
(6, 'Students are enrolled in Computer Science and Maths')
```

Comment: That makes sense now thank you.  I keep forgetting that variables shouldn't have the same name.  I said in my original post that I was beginner and it's really great receiving this feedback.  Thanks Logic (definitely logical!).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
in_both_classes = []
for math_student in math_students:
    for cs_student in cs_students:
        if math_student == cs_student:
            in_both_classes.append(math_student)

print "There are {} students in both classes: {}".format(
    len(in_both_classes),
    ", ".join(in_both_classes),
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom!  Didn't expect an answer that quickly.  Yours looks a lot 'cleaner' than mine but there's no way I'll be able to use that print statement as we haven't done joins yet either!!  Are you able to tell me what I was doing wrong in my example?  Thanks again, Louise

Comment: @Louise Sure, the biggest problem in your code was that both your loops were using the same variable name for the 'counter' (`student`). But on top of that, you effectively had 3 loops - the two obvious ones (`for x in y`) and a hidden loop, caused by `if student in math_students`. When you ask python `if thing in my_list` it actually loops over each item in the list to find out. Effectively, you were solving the entire problem as many times as you had maths students - the outer loop was completely unnecessary. That's why you got the correct list of students, but repeated 13 times.

Comment: @myaut there was no need, I've simplified it now.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing wrong but couldn't work out how to correct it until you provided your solution. Thank you so much Tom.  It keeps saying we shouldn't say thanks but I don't understand why? (for posts?).

Answer (score 1):

when you retrieve the two lists, you use the same variable name `studnet`, you should rename any of them, for instance `s1` and `s2` and increase count only when s1 equal to s2.

BTW, I have another suggestion,  you can use `Sets Intersection`

```
math_students = ["Audrey", "Ben", "Julia", "Paul", "Gerry", "Sue",
             "Helena", "Harry", "Marco", "Rachel", "Tina", "Mark", "Jackson"]
cs_students = ["William", "Aroha", "Melissa", "Sue", "Ben", "Audrey", "Susan", "Mark", "Hemi", "Brendan", "Paul", "Barry", "Julia"]

math_set = set(math_students)
cs_set = set(cs_students)

# students in both cs and math
common_set = math_set & cs_set

#the studnets only in cs
only_cs = cs_set - math_set

# the students only in math
only_math = math_set - cs_set


print common_set
print "----"
print only_cs
print "----"
print only_math
```

Comment: Before my post was edited I explained that we weren't allowed to use sets for this question as it had to be with nested loops.  It still amazes me how many different ways this can be done in Python but thanks for providing another solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to filter people that are in both math class and computer science class:

```
# contains only the students in both original lists
both = [i for i in math_students if i in cs_students]

for student in both:
    # interpolating the name of each student in both list
    print '{} is enrolled in both classes'.format(student)

# interpolating the number of students in the both list
print '{} students are in both classes'.format(len(both))
```